# increasing width on hover, on a square padding-top:100% div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to increase the width of a div on hover while the height stays the same. This is tough because I get the height from padding-top: 100% which allows it to be a resizable square. So naturally as I increase the width the height organically increases too. (It is important the div height and width are equal in its normal state so it's a perfect square)

I'm now lost and unsure how to achieve this, any input is appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/9tc2mbwd/2/

```
.work-container { padding-top: 100%; }
```

Comment: So you need the `padding-top` property, because you set the width of the div to the 30% of its container, which has no absolute size, and you want the hight to be the same?

Comment: Yes the width and height need to be the same in its normal state. I'll make that clearer.

Comment: Just your friendly reminder to choose a correct answer if you see one -- it helps everyone out a little bit!

Comment: Haven't forgotten, I'm playing around with Jefsama's answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to set fix width and height into `.work-wrapper`, then..
Make the `.work-container` the hovered element, and do like this:

```css
.work-wrapper {
 width: 30%;
}
.work-container {
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
.work-container:hover {
  width: 200%;
}
.work-1 {
  background-color: #FEF102;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-wrapper">
    <div class="work-container work-1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like the best answer, I'll see if it works and come back to mark it correct :)

Comment: Hope my answer is the best for your need :)

Comment: Sure was, not sure how I didn't think of this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport units and get rid of work-wrapper, like this:

```css
.work-container {
 width: 30vw;
 height: 30vw;
 transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.work-container:hover {
 width: 50vw;
}

.work-1 {
 background-color: #FEF102;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-container work-1">
</div>
```

Comment: Useful tip but unfortunately it's inside another div, it's % isn't based on viewport width.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can start off by getting rid of the percentages and adding this to " .work-wrapper":

```
width:150px;
height:150px;
overflow: hidden;
```

and keep everything the same!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but it needs to be fully responsive, thus the % values.